# Reload Helper from Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I'm calling helper methods from the Rails console in Rails 3 like this:

```
>> helper.my_method(parameter)
>> #=> some result
```

However, if I change the helper method the changes are not reflected when I call the same method again. I have to `exit` and run `rails console` in order to see the changes to the helper method take effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to run `reload!` and *most* classes will be reloaded, including your helpers.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, `helper` is an instantiated object that memoizes the ApplicationController helpers, which will not be reloaded when you call `reload!`, at least in Rails 4.  You can work around this by calling `ApplicationController.helpers.my_method(parameter)` in the console.  You will still need to use `reload!` when you edit the helper, but it will reload unlike `helper`.

Comment: The memoization [has been removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/fa65b44b28b7c3de3b18b3431a7e76a6bef7f495) as of Rails 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

After coming across this problem twice now and giving up, I figured out how to reload helpers without exiting the console and not calling them via `ApplicationController.helpers.my_method(parameter)`.

After calling `reload!`, include your helper *again* (`include MyHelper`) and it will include your recently changed helper.